# Destucturing object in ES6 function definition Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, traceur

I'm using traceur to create a basic ES6 example, but I'm getting the error "unexpected identifier" in chrome (with experimental js on) followed by the output.  Plnkr doesn't output anything at all. http://plnkr.co/edit/ruhoFM9r8nBabtvr87Cy?p=preview

My question is, why is this not working in plnkr.  And are there more reliable ways to start writing ES6 today?

```
let getCar = function({make, model, speed}) {
  return `The ${make} ${model} is a ${speed} speed`;
};

let audi = {
  make: 'Audi',
  model: 'S5',
  speed: 6
};

console.log(getCar(audi));
```

Comment: Does traceur support destructuring in arguments at all?

Comment: @Bergi Yes it has just about full support for destructuring.  I'm getting the correct output using Traceur in chrome, but prior to the output, chrome throws an Unexpected identifier.

Comment: @Bergi http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: Firefox is happy with that code if  `let`  is replaced with `var`. But without changes it it complains about a missing `;`.

Comment: Uh, Chrome seems to complain about the `let`. Looks like the script is parsed as ES5?

Comment: Haha, I found out what my issue was.  I had two <script> tags pointing to the same script.  One had type="module" one did not.  Sorry to waste your time guys.

Comment: Was about to to say that 6to5 transpiled this without any problems, but now I don't need to :)